# python 3 making terminal interactive scripts

Tags: python, shell, terminal

i am programming in python 3 and i want to know how to make a tool that

1. changes what the terminal refers to user as, like routersploit.
2. changes text color in terminal
3. correctly runs in terminal window.

as of right now i have an sh file that echos the startup, and cds into the directory of the .py file, and runs the file. The file runs and goes through a yes/no confirm boot using:

```
def bootloader(): 
  boot = input("boot yes/no: ") 
  if boot == "yes":
     print("booting") 
  elif boot == no: 
     print("boot cancelled")
```

but every time i run the file in the shell, it says yes or no not defined.

Comment: you probably should use `raw_input`

Comment: you should probably split the question on two one for the color/name part and one for the bug in your python script.

Comment: (1) would require a change to the $PS1 (at least on my machine) environment variable. (2) could mostly be accomplished by a change to $PS1, but you might want to change what 'no color' is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`no`, in `boot == no`, needs to be a string so you need to change it to this `"no"` instead.

```
def bootloader(): 
  boot = input("boot yes/no: ") 
  if boot == "yes":
     print("booting") 
  elif boot == "no": 
     print("boot cancelled")
```

Also as explained [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Input_and_Output), `input` uses `raw_input` function implicitly to load the user input as a string and tries to evalute it before the assignement to the `boot` variable. So you are better off using `raw_input`. Thus change your code as follows:

```
def bootloader(): 
  boot = raw_input("boot yes/no: ") 
  if boot == "yes":
     print("booting") 
  elif boot == "no": 
     print("boot cancelled")
```